# newbie rails question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested, scaffolding

i have a basic rails 3 question..

i have a list of jobs in my db and each job is tied to a particular location..in short i have one location to many jobs..

i have created scaffolding jobs and locations and created the appropriate references.

i want to create a list of jobs such that when i click on one of the jobs, i get to see a list of all the jobs in that location.

how can i do this in rails 3?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you have a Job class with

```
belongs_to :location
```

and a Location with

```
has_many :jobs
```

Then you can access all jobs for the location of one job via

```
@jobs = job.location.jobs
```

Then, depending on the details of your setup, you can do something like this in a view:

```
<%= render @jobs %>
```